# Click on cancel button to return to the previous page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a cancel button and I need in a template to get the url of the previous page, so in case user click cancel to go back.

Previous page, usually, is a list or detail page.

In case of detail, I have the object, so it easier to go back, but what I do in case of a list page, also how do I know the previous is detail or list page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following javascript command will return you to the previous page.

`javascript:window.history.back()`

**Example:**

`< a href="javascript:window.history.back()">Cancel< /a>`

Answer (score 1):

Django solution:

```
<a href="{{ your_object.get_absolute_url }}">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: this works, only if I'm navigating from the object detail page, but if I'm navigating from object list, will go to the wrong back page